# iterating csv and running tcl script in shell script

Tags: shell

Im reading a csv file and removing header and passing all the arguements to a tcl script, the script is running for only 1 row from the CSV file but not iterating the records in CSV. Did I missed any looping logic? Please help thanks in advance

```
#!/bin/bash
    read_properties()
    {
    i=1
    sed 1d FF_CONFIG_FILE.csv | while IFS=',' read -r arguments;
    do
            run_script arguments
    done
    }

    run_script()
    {
    exec TCL_sqoop_script.sh arguments
    }

    read_properties
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try without exec keyword as below;

```
..
run_script()
    {
    TCL_sqoop_script.sh arguments
    }
...
```